# Stack Exchange app - listing my tags

Tags: support, android-app

How do I get the app to show me a relevant listing of my tags?    When I go into the stack overflow section of the app, and ask it to show me "my tags, unanswered"  I get a list that dates back 3 or 4 years.   The first 8 or so are from 2010 and 2011.  Arguably useless to me.

Is there a way to say "unanswered, my tags, sort by most recent first"?

**Edit**: Added link to screenshots :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0nhj.jpg

In the end, I'd like to see things that are relevant to me.   All the other choices (active, recent, hot) or even the feed... bring back mostly items I've no interest or experience in.

Comment: Android, sorry.    In my list I can see news, active, etc...  The last choice is "Unanswered (my tags)".   I would expect it sorts it by most recent, but it doesn't.   My first 10 or so are from the stone ages.

Comment: Here's a link to what I'm talking about..   http://imgur.com/a/ghHPs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just search for

```
answers:0 intags:mine
```

and pick "newest" in the sort-picker.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thank you much.